# Why does subclassing in Python slow things down so much?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, dictionary, subclass

I was working on a simple class that extends `dict`, and I realized that key lookup and use of `pickle` are *very* slow.

I thought it was a problem with my class, so I did some trivial benchmarks:

```sh
(venv) marco@buzz:~/sources/python-frozendict/test$ python --version
Python 3.9.0a0
(venv) marco@buzz:~/sources/python-frozendict/test$ sudo pyperf system tune --affinity 3
[sudo] password for marco: 
Tune the system configuration to run benchmarks

Actions
=======

CPU Frequency: Minimum frequency of CPU 3 set to the maximum frequency

System state
============

CPU: use 1 logical CPUs: 3
Perf event: Maximum sample rate: 1 per second
ASLR: Full randomization
Linux scheduler: No CPU is isolated
CPU Frequency: 0-3=min=max=2600 MHz
CPU scaling governor (intel_pstate): performance
Turbo Boost (intel_pstate): Turbo Boost disabled
IRQ affinity: irqbalance service: inactive
IRQ affinity: Default IRQ affinity: CPU 0-2
IRQ affinity: IRQ affinity: IRQ 0,2=CPU 0-3; IRQ 1,3-17,51,67,120-131=CPU 0-2
Power supply: the power cable is plugged

Advices
=======

Linux scheduler: Use isolcpus=<cpu list> kernel parameter to isolate CPUs
Linux scheduler: Use rcu_nocbs=<cpu list> kernel parameter (with isolcpus) to not schedule RCU on isolated CPUs
(venv) marco@buzz:~/sources/python-frozendict/test$ python -m pyperf timeit --rigorous --affinity 3 -s '                    
x = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4}
' 'x[4]'
.........................................
Mean +- std dev: 35.2 ns +- 1.8 ns
(venv) marco@buzz:~/sources/python-frozendict/test$ python -m pyperf timeit --rigorous --affinity 3 -s '
class A(dict):
    pass             

x = A({0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4})
' 'x[4]'
.........................................
Mean +- std dev: 60.1 ns +- 2.5 ns
(venv) marco@buzz:~/sources/python-frozendict/test$ python -m pyperf timeit --rigorous --affinity 3 -s '
x = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4}
' '5 in x'
.........................................
Mean +- std dev: 31.9 ns +- 1.4 ns
(venv) marco@buzz:~/sources/python-frozendict/test$ python -m pyperf timeit --rigorous --affinity 3 -s '
class A(dict):
    pass

x = A({0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4})
' '5 in x'
.........................................
Mean +- std dev: 64.7 ns +- 5.4 ns
(venv) marco@buzz:~/sources/python-frozendict/test$ python
Python 3.9.0a0 (heads/master-dirty:d8ca2354ed, Oct 30 2019, 20:25:01) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190909] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> class A(dict):
...     def __reduce__(self):                 
...         return (A, (dict(self), ))
... 
>>> timeit("dumps(x)", """
... from pickle import dumps
... x = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4}
... """, number=10000000)
6.70694484282285
>>> timeit("dumps(x)", """
... from pickle import dumps
... x = A({0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4})
... """, number=10000000, globals={"A": A})
31.277778962627053
>>> timeit("loads(x)", """
... from pickle import dumps, loads
... x = dumps({0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4})
... """, number=10000000)
5.767975459806621
>>> timeit("loads(x)", """
... from pickle import dumps, loads
... x = dumps(A({0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4}))
... """, number=10000000, globals={"A": A})
22.611666693352163
```

The results are really a surprise. While key lookup is 2x slower, `pickle` is *5x* slower.

How can this be? Other methods, like `get()`,`__eq__()` and `__init__()`, and iteration over `keys()`, `values()` and `items()` are as fast as `dict`.

---

**EDIT**: I took a look at the source code of Python 3.9, and in `Objects/dictobject.c` it seems that the `__getitem__()` method is implemented by `dict_subscript()`. And `dict_subscript()` slows down subclasses only if the key is missing, since the subclass can implement `__missing__()` and it tries to see if it exists. But the benchmark was with an existing key.

But I noticed something: `__getitem__()` is defined with the flag `METH_COEXIST`. And also `__contains__()`, the other method that is 2x slower, has the same flag. From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/c-api/structures.html#METH_COEXIST):

> The method will be loaded in place of existing definitions. Without
>   METH_COEXIST, the default is to skip repeated definitions. Since slot
>   wrappers are loaded before the method table, the existence of a
>   sq_contains slot, for example, would generate a wrapped method named
>   **contains**() and preclude the loading of a corresponding PyCFunction with the same name. With the flag defined, the PyCFunction will be
>   loaded in place of the wrapper object and will co-exist with the slot.
>   This is helpful because calls to PyCFunctions are optimized more than
>   wrapper object calls.

So if I understood correctly, in theory `METH_COEXIST` should speed things up, but it seems to have the opposite effect. Why?

---

**EDIT 2**: I discovered something more.

`__getitem__()` and `__contains()__` are flagged as `METH_COEXIST`, because they are declared in PyDict_Type **two** times.

They are both present, one time, in the slot `tp_methods`, where they are explicitly declared as `__getitem__()` and `__contains()__`. But the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_methods) says that `tp_methods` are **not** inherited by subclasses.

So a subclass of `dict` does not call `__getitem__()`, but calls the subslot `mp_subscript`. Indeed, `mp_subscript` is contained in the slot `tp_as_mapping`, that permits a subclass to inherit its subslots.

The problem is that both `__getitem__()` and `mp_subscript` use the **same** function, `dict_subscript`. Is it possible that it's only the way it was inherited that slows it down?

Comment: I'm not able to find the specific part of the source code, but I believe there is a fast path in the C implementation which checks if the object is a `dict` and if so, calls the C implementation directly instead of looking up the `__getitem__` method from the object's class. Your code therefore does two dict lookups, the first one for the key `'__getitem__'` in the dictionary of class `A`'s members, so it can be expected to be about twice as slow. The `pickle` explanation is probably quite similar.

Comment: @kaya3: But if it is so, why `len()`, for example, is not 2x slower but has the same speed?

Comment: I'm not sure about that; I would have thought `len` should have a fast path for built-in sequence types. I don't think I'm able to give a proper answer to your question, but it's a good one, so hopefully someone more knowledgeable about Python internals than me will answer it.

Comment: I've done some investigation and updated the question.

Comment: Weird... I've looked at the code, and I don't see *anything* that should be more efficient for exact dicts than for dict subclasses in the code involved for `in`. It shouldn't be looking up `__contains__` (it should go to `sq_contains`, which should be the same function for both `dict` and subclasses), and there's no fast path in either `COMPARE_OP` or `PyDict_Contains` (the `dict` implementation of `sq_contains`).

Comment: ...oh. I see it now. The explicit `__contains__` implementation is blocking the logic used for inheriting `sq_contains`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Indexing and `in` are slower in `dict` subclasses because of a bad interaction between a `dict` optimization and the logic subclasses use to inherit C slots. This should be fixable, though not from your end.

The CPython implementation has two sets of hooks for operator overloads. There are Python-level methods like `__contains__` and `__getitem__`, but there's also a separate set of slots for C function pointers in the memory layout of a type object. Usually, either the Python method will be a wrapper around the C implementation, or the C slot will contain a function that searches for and calls the Python method. It's more efficient for the C slot to implement the operation directly, as the C slot is what Python actually accesses.

Mappings written in C implement the C slots `sq_contains` and `mp_subscript` to provide `in` and indexing. Ordinarily, the Python-level `__contains__` and `__getitem__` methods would be automatically generated as wrappers around the C functions, but the `dict` class has [explicit implementations](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Objects/dictobject.c) of `__contains__` and `__getitem__`, because the explicit implementations are a bit faster than the generated wrappers:

```
static PyMethodDef mapp_methods[] = {
    DICT___CONTAINS___METHODDEF
    {"__getitem__", (PyCFunction)(void(*)(void))dict_subscript,        METH_O | METH_COEXIST,
     getitem__doc__},
    ...
```

(Actually, the explicit `__getitem__` implementation is the same function as the `mp_subscript` implementation, just with a different kind of wrapper.)

Ordinarily, a subclass would inherit its parent's implementations of C-level hooks like `sq_contains` and `mp_subscript`, and the subclass would be just as fast as the superclass. However, the logic in [`update_one_slot`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Objects/typeobject.c#L7202) looks for the parent implementation by trying to find the generated wrapper methods through an MRO search.

`dict` doesn't *have* generated wrappers for `sq_contains` and `mp_subscript`, because it provides explicit `__contains__` and `__getitem__` implementations.

Instead of inheriting `sq_contains` and `mp_subscript`, `update_one_slot` ends up giving the subclass `sq_contains` and `mp_subscript` implementations that perform an MRO search for `__contains__` and `__getitem__` and call those. This is much less efficient than inheriting the C slots directly.

Fixing this will require changes to the `update_one_slot` implementation.

---

Aside from what I described above, `dict_subscript` also looks up `__missing__` for dict subclasses, so fixing the slot inheritance issue won't make subclasses completely on par with `dict` itself for lookup speed, but it should get them a lot closer.

---

As for pickling, on the `dumps` side, the pickle implementation has a [dedicated fast path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Modules/_pickle.c#L4291) for dicts, while the dict subclass takes a more roundabout path through `object.__reduce_ex__` and `save_reduce`.

On the `loads` side, the time difference is mostly just from the extra opcodes and lookups to retrieve and instantiate the `__main__.A` class, while dicts have a dedicated pickle opcode for making a new dict. If we compare the disassembly for the pickles:

```
In [26]: pickletools.dis(pickle.dumps({0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}))                                                                                                                                                           
    0: \x80 PROTO      4
    2: \x95 FRAME      25
   11: }    EMPTY_DICT
   12: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 0)
   13: (    MARK
   14: K        BININT1    0
   16: K        BININT1    0
   18: K        BININT1    1
   20: K        BININT1    1
   22: K        BININT1    2
   24: K        BININT1    2
   26: K        BININT1    3
   28: K        BININT1    3
   30: K        BININT1    4
   32: K        BININT1    4
   34: u        SETITEMS   (MARK at 13)
   35: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 4

In [27]: pickletools.dis(pickle.dumps(A({0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4})))                                                                                                                                                        
    0: \x80 PROTO      4
    2: \x95 FRAME      43
   11: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE '__main__'
   21: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 0)
   22: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'A'
   25: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 1)
   26: \x93 STACK_GLOBAL
   27: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 2)
   28: )    EMPTY_TUPLE
   29: \x81 NEWOBJ
   30: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 3)
   31: (    MARK
   32: K        BININT1    0
   34: K        BININT1    0
   36: K        BININT1    1
   38: K        BININT1    1
   40: K        BININT1    2
   42: K        BININT1    2
   44: K        BININT1    3
   46: K        BININT1    3
   48: K        BININT1    4
   50: K        BININT1    4
   52: u        SETITEMS   (MARK at 31)
   53: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 4
```

we see that the difference between the two is that the second pickle needs a whole bunch of opcodes to look up `__main__.A` and instantiate it, while the first pickle just does `EMPTY_DICT` to get an empty dict. After that, both pickles push the same keys and values onto the pickle operand stack and run `SETITEMS`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Have you any idea why CPython uses this strange inheriting method? I mean, is there not a way to declare `__contains__()` and `__getitem()` in such a way that can be inherited by subclasses? In the official documentation of `tp_methods`, it's written that `methods are inherited through a different mechanism`, so it seems possible.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: `__contains__` and `__getitem__` *are* inherited, but the problem is that `sq_contains` and `mp_subscript` are not.

Comment: Mh, well.... wait a moment. I thought it was the contrary. `__contains__` and `__getitem__` are in the slot `tp_methods`, that for the official docs are not inherited by subclasses. And as you said, `update_one_slot` does not uses `sq_contains` and `mp_subscript`.

Comment: In poor words, `contains` and the rest can't be simply moved in another slot, that is inherited by subclasses?

Comment: @MarcoSulla: `tp_methods` isn't inherited, but the Python method objects generated from it are inherited in the sense that the standard MRO search for attribute access will find them.

Comment: As for moving the slots, that wouldn't help. There is *already* code to inherit `sq_contains` and `mp_subscript`, but it fails for the reasons described in the answer. Moving the slots around wouldn't fix that.

Comment: Ook... and what about `pickle`? Do you think there's some thing I can do to improve the speed? I mean, 5x is really a problem.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: Maybe you could write a custom `__reduce_ex__` method or something, but I wouldn't expect much benefit, if any.